# MongoDB first query slow

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm getting really weird behaviour from mongodb.

I have a sharded session tracking collection were i do findOne's only on the _id (=shard key).

Before getting the session data I get the site data (non sharded collection) also with findOne (also on the _id), I cache the site data in memcached, this way the tracking findOne takes about 0.04 seconds to fetch.

However when I disable memcached on the site data and force it to get the data from mongodb the tracking findOne takes 0.001 seconds and the site findOne now is slow.

Explain situation 2 with findOne site first: http://pastebin.com/qTX0az7H

Explain situation 1 with findOne tracking first: http://pastebin.com/bBSXUEKh

I'm using the PHP driver 1.4.4 and mongodb version v2.4.6

Comment: It is the OS caching the working set of MongoDB on fist run, also could be network latency on first run

Comment: Could you try not using `findOne`, but just `find`? I found that `findOne` is actually slower than `find`...

Comment: network latency between nodes avg 0.401ms so I don't think that would be the issue, it could be the OS caching the working set but how would I measure this? explain() doesn't really show anything to me.

Comment: @RickyA I see almost no difference between find and findOne performance wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was due to using the Mongo class instead of the MongoClient class in php to connect.